# How to load ngOninit after binding the api's?

Tags: angular

I am trying to load a Crud screen which contains two api's. I want to load the ngonit after loading the two(or more api's).This below code shows the loading of the Rule types. I have similar query for Grouptypes. But I dont want to use the setimeout function for loading the api's..

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {        
        console.log(this.data);
       

        this.isNew = this.data.isNew;
      
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.getRuleTypes(this.data);
           this.getGroupTypes(this.data);
        }, 1000);

      
        console.log(this.ruleTypeselected );
        console.log(this.groupTypeselected);
        this.title = this.isNew === false ? this.data.title:'';
        this.editForm.reset(this.data.editDataItem);
       
    }
   
    public getRuleTypes(data:any): any{
        this.ruleService.readRuleTypes().subscribe(res=>{
            this.ruleTypes=res;
            if(data.isNew === true){
                this.ruleTypeselected = res[0];
            }  else {
                if (this.ruleTypes[this.ruleTypes.findIndex(s => s.ruleTypeName === data.editDataItem.ruleType)] !== undefined) {
                    this.ruleTypeselected = this.ruleTypes[this.ruleTypes.findIndex(s => s.ruleTypeName === data.editDataItem.ruleType)];
                }
            }          
        });
    }
    public getGroupTypes(data:any): any{
        this.ruleService.readGroupTypes().subscribe(res=>{
            this.groupTypes=res;
            if(data.isNew === true){
                this.groupTypeselected = res[0];
            }  else {
                if (this.groupTypes[this.groupTypes.findIndex(s => s.groupTypeName === data.editDataItem.groupType)] !== undefined) {
                    this.groupTypeselected = this.groupTypes[this.groupTypes.findIndex(s => s.groupTypeName === data.editDataItem.groupType)];
                }
            }          
        });
    }
```

Kindly help me with better solutions or better way to write the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My brother. NgOnInit is not designed for this. This component is for initial setup. If you want to predefined data, use these in the routing, such as `resolve` for data create before component inited or `activate` for check permission or navigate to other page.

What is the point of specifying in retrospect what rights the user has? If bot use site, it can click before you define roles within timeout. I don't think that's a good idea.

You can use your service in both:

- https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate
- https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

**Purpose of CanActivate goal:** "Can I load the component (true, false) or have to navigate to somewhere (UrlTree)?"

**Purpose of Resolve:** "Before I load the component, what data should I already have?"

Angular will first use "activate" if configured (true by default), and if this is true, it will run "resovle" if configured (empty object by default).

---

If this is dynamic for you, it can change at any time, then the other respondent’s solution will be good. Not only subscribe, you have to also **unsubscribe** in ngOnDestroy. **Otherwise you will have memory leak.** Ofc, if you send `complete` signal, it will unsubscribe by automatically.

---

**Update for help**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you have to dynamic solution, but I not recommend!

[image]

If dynamic I prefer this. Not need unsubscribe, it will automatic. Less chance of error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brother I need to implement like the one used like const call back in js. Is it allowable to use promise(resolve,) like operation in the above query? So the above  Reoslve and Canactivate help are helpfull?

Comment: resolve can return: Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T where T is a type. So you can return promise. :)
I usually use, check in activate service value by pipe. If invalid (error, reject) when navigate to antoher page. If true when use resolve. Ofc, you will get raw data (not observable, or promise) in component. If you wait 1-2 mins I will update my question with a example.

Comment: Which solution did you like? Just asking. :)

Comment: The Second One ,dynamic with unsubscribe(). Thanks @Numich

Answer (score 1):

you can delete your getRuleType and call the service in your NgOnInit

```
public ngOnInit(): void {        
this.ruleService.readRuleTypes().subscribe(res=>{
            this.ruleTypes=res;
            if(data.isNew === true){
                this.ruleTypeselected = res[0];
            } 
            }          
        });
 }
```

I suggest strongly the use of observable for a better reactive programming, so If you can adjust so that you can provide obervables to your template, this would let your code look cleaner.

Comment: as much subscriber as services you have, but do not forget to unsubscribe after that in ngOnDestroy hook.
But As I told you, it is preferable to use Observables

Comment: If you need async, so you have to use Observables and Subjects