# Cannot bind Select Options in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bind this data to DropDown or Select options. The value is not binding to the form controller. this problem is extention of :

[How to load ngOninit after binding the api's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818652/how-to-load-ngoninit-after-binding-the-apis/64818947#64818947)

**Component.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label padding-bottom-Mini">Rule Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="ruleTypeName">
                <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Choose your Rule Types</option>
                 option *ngFor="let rule of ruleTypes" [value]="rule">  {{ rule.ruleTypeName }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
   public ngOnInit(): void {    

 if(this.data.isNew === true) {
            this.editForm =   this.formBuilder.group({
                    id              : new FormControl(),
                    name            : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                    description     : new FormControl(''),
                    libraryFile     : new FormControl(''),       
                    className       : new FormControl(''),
                    ruleTypeName    : new FormControl(''),
                    groupTypeName   : new FormControl('')
                });
            } else {
                this.editForm =   this.formBuilder.group({
                    name            : new FormControl(this.data.editDataItem.name, Validators.required),
                    description     : new FormControl(this.data.editDataItem.description),
                    libraryFile     : new FormControl(this.data.editDataItem.libraryFile),       
                    className       : new FormControl(this.data.editDataItem.className),
                    ruleTypeName    : new FormControl(this.data.editDataItem.ruleTypeName),
                    groupTypeName   : new FormControl(this.data.editDataItem.groupTypeName)
                });
            }
    this.ruleTypeName=this.getRuleTypes(this.data);


   }

public getRuleTypes(data:any): any{
        this.ruleService.readRuleTypes().subscribe((res:any)=>{
            this.ruleTypes=res;
            console.log(this.ruleTypes);
            if(data.isNew === true){
                this.ruleTypeName = null;
            }  else {
                if (this.ruleTypes[this.ruleTypes.findIndex(s => s.ruleTypeName === data.editDataItem.ruleType)] !== undefined) {
                    this.ruleTypeName = this.ruleTypes[this.ruleTypes.findIndex(s => s.ruleTypeName === data.editDataItem.ruleType)];
                   // this.editForm.controls["ruleTypeName"].setValue(this.ruleTypeName.ruleTypeName);
                }
            }  
            this.editForm.controls["ruleTypeName"].setValue(this.ruleTypeName.ruleTypeName);               
        });
        
    }
```

Dont know what I'm missing here...Please help with relevant datas.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your behavior with a simple snippet, but it is working for me. Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knpkzv?file=src/app/app.component.html. Can you maybe share a stackblitz showing the not working behavior? PS.: Instead of `if (this.ruleTypes[this.ruleTypes.findIndex(s => s.ruleTypeName === data.editDataItem.ruleType)] !== undefined) {` say `if (this.ruleTypes.some(s => s.ruleTypeName === data.editDataItem.ruleType)) {`

Comment: Hi MoxxiManagarm,Would you check this eg.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bwr1hd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, Make little bit change in Array, arraytype etc.

Comment: You are missing a '<' at component html line 6.

Comment: Your select stores the value `option`, but your formcontrol has a `string` value. You need to change the `[value]` tag to `[value]="option.Name"`. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n3xpfx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @bahadrdsr, which line.? <form [formGroup]="editForm">
 <select formControlName="myValue">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option.Name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your value attribute in your template.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label padding-bottom-Mini">Rule Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="ruleTypeName">
                <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Choose your Rule Types</option>
                 <option *ngFor="let rule of ruleTypes" [value]="rule.ruleTypeName">  {{ rule.ruleTypeName }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```